# The Architecture type of a HTML5 cross-platform Application

Tags: android, sqlite, google-chrome, jquery-mobile, cordova

[image]

I'm working on a HTML5 cross-platform Survey application using jquery mobile, phoneGap , and sqlite database with web Storage !!!!
For Now I'm testing this App on Android Plateform using eclipse .
I'm new to the mobile world , I'm more familiar with j2ee web applications 
So i'm wondering what can we call this type of architecture especially that I'm not working with a real server such glassFish ,TomCat .. or even a real SGBD and that everything is on the web browser (I'm using chrome)
Could Any one Help me with this ?
thank u :)
Here is the list of possible styles of architecture but I can't find the suitable one for my case !!!

Comment: Web View in android is able to display any kind of html page that has script when it is enabled programmatically as like your pc mobile is also connected to a wireless network so it can do and android is software stack with the base of linux that is power of android to give the functionalities of Client server communicaiton

Comment: This's an HTML5 application so it has no relation with android .Android is used just to test the application.

Comment: Please try to re-write your question

Comment: I'm asking about the style of architecture used in a mobile cross-platform application Among the different styles of architecture (Client/Server , N-Tier / 3-Tier ... )  !!!

Comment: HTML5 is a language, NOT an 'Architecture type'.

But you can use HTML5 in your Architecture type. Example HTML5 is the Client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're building HTML5 loader apps on multiple platforms, depending on if you are storing your HTML5 locally or pulling it off a server, that's your answer for Server/Client.

You'll want *object orient* your javascript so you don't pollute the namespace.  If you are scripting on the backend, also a good practise... I think object oriented goes without saying these days.

You can tier out your javascript to have a frontend generator, business logic layer, and data layer to handle your transactions with sqlite.  Or you could also follow a MVC tiered setup.

If you are pushing data from the device to a central repository (which I think you must), you could build SOA on the server to handle the ingestion of data.